# error: main.c:(.text+0x32a): undefined reference to `angulo_1'

Tags: c

Al intentar compilar el siguiente programa me lanza el error que he especificado en el título, ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? la problemática a resolver es la siguiente:

*Observe la solicitud al usuario de 2 coordenadas para 2 puntos distintos punto A y punto B.*

*Se deberá de obtener mediante el uso de funciones lo siguiente:*

- *Distancia entre puntos A y B.*
- *Ecuación de la recta de intersección de ambos puntos.*
- *Pendiente de la recta.*
- *Suma de A+B entendiendo que A+B=(x1+x2)+i(y1+y2)*
- *Resta de A-B entendiendo que A-B=(x1-x2)+i(y1-y2)*
- *Producto de AB*
- *División de A/B*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

float modulo_1(float x1, float y1);
float modulo_2(float x2, float y2); 
float angulo_1(float x1, float y1);
float angulo_2(float x2, float y2);
float dist(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2);
float pend(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2); 
float recta(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2);
float sumx(float x1, float x2);
float sumy(float y1, float y2);
float restx(float x1, float x2); 
float resty(float y1, float y2); 

/*funciones*/
float modulo_1(float x1, float y1){
  float modulo_1;
  modulo_1=sqrt((x1*x1)+(y1*y1));
  return modulo_1;
}

float angulo_2(float x2, float y2){
  float m2, rad2, angulo_2,val_pi;
  val_pi=3.1415;
  m2=(-y2)/(-x2);
  rad2=atan(m2);
  angulo_2=(rad2)*(180/val_pi);
  return angulo_2;
}

float dist(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2){
  float dist; 
  dist= sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
  return dist; 
}

float pend (float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2){
  float pend; 
  pend=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
  return pend; 
}

float recta(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2){
  float recta=((pend(x1,y1,x2,y2))*-x1)+y1;
  return recta; 
}

float sumx(float x1, float x2){
  float sumx; 
  sumx=x1+x2;
  return sumx; 
}

float sumy(float y1, float y2){
  float sumy; 
  sumy=y1+y2;
  return sumy; 
}

float restx(float x1, float x2){
  float restx; 
  restx=x1-x2;
  return restx;
}

float resty(float y1, float y2){
  float resty; 
  resty=y1-y2;
  return resty;
}
/*funcion principal*/
int main(){
  float x1,x2,y1,y2;
  
  printf("dame los valores de [x1,y1] [x2,y2] separados por la tecla espacio");
  scanf("%f%f%f%f",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);

  printf("\n\n");
  printf("coordenadas del 1er punto: %.1f,%.1f\n",x1,y1);
  printf("el modulo del 1er punto es: %.1f\n", modulo_1(x1,y1));
  printf("el angulo del 1er punto es: %.2f%c\n\n", angulo_1(x1,y1),248);

  printf("coordenadas del 2do punto: %.1f,%.1f\n",x2,y2);
  printf("el modulo del 2do punto es: %.1f\n", modulo_2(x2,y2));
  printf("el angulo del 2do punto es: %.2f%c\n", angulo_1(x2,y2),248);

  printf("\n la distancia entre los puntos es de: %.1f\n", dist(x1,x2,y1,y2));
  printf("\n la ecuacion de interseccion de ambos puntos es %.1fx-y+%.1f=0\n", pend(x1,x2,y1,y2),recta(x1,x2,y1,y2));
  printf("\n la pendiente de la recta es: %.1f \n", pend(x2,y2,x1,y1));
  printf("\n la suma de ambos puntos es: %.1f+i%.1f\n", sumx(x1,x2),sumy(y1,y2));
  printf("\n la resta de ambos puntos es: %.1f-i%.1f\n", restx(x1,x2),resty(y1,y2));
  printf("\n el producto de ambos puntos es: %.1f angulo %.1f%c\n", modulo_1(x1,y1)*modulo_2(x2,y2),angulo_1(x1,y1)+angulo_2(x2,y2),248);
  printf("\n la division de ambos puntos es: %.1f angulo %.1f%c\n", modulo_1(x1,y1)/modulo_2(x2,y2),angulo_1(x1,y1)-angulo_2(x2,y2),248);

  return 0;
```

Comment: Salta a la vista que declaras una función llamada `angulo_1( )`, la llamas en varios sitios, pero **no le das ningún cuerpo**. Normal que el compilador se queje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error `undefined reference to '...'` significa que el enlazador no pudo encontrar la implementación de la función.

En tu código te faltó escribirla. Puedes empezar por esto:

```
float angulo_2(float x2, float y2){
    ...
}
```

Recuerda que la elipsis (`...`) es simbólica y se usa para indicar que algo debería ir ahí, como en matemática. Así que quítala para compilar sino dará error.